# trouble using TFS Git Rest api to retrieve tree

Tags: git, rest, tfs, tfs-2015

I'm having trouble using the TFS Rest API for Git to retrieve a tree.

The relevant code is

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Accept", 'application/zip')
$DownloadTreeCmd = "http://tfs.mycompany.com:8080/tfs/myCollection/_apis/git/repositories/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/trees/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?api-version=1.0&filename=TempDownload.zip&recursive=1" 

$nresp = Invoke-RestMethod $DownloadTreeCmd -UseDefaultCredentials -Headers $headers
```

I end up with something in the $nrest that I can't read. I've tried writing it to a file but it is not recognized as a zip file. I can see data in I appears to be binary data.

What should I be doing with this data.

Answer (score 0):

It's working but I can't explain why it wasn't working before.

I got this to work but I'm not sure I understand this. 
The filename parameter on the uri does not appear to do anything. The returned object can't be saved into a file of type .zip (actually you can save it but zip does not recognize it as an archive).

To make this work I simply removed the filename from the uri request and add -OutFile xxxx.zip to the Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet.